# Caching images with different query strings (S3 signed urls)

Tags: http, caching, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out if I can get browsers to cache images with signed urls.

What I want is to generate a new signed url for every request (same image, but with an updated signature), but have the browser not re-download it every time.

So, assuming the cache-related headers are set correctly, and all of the URL is the same except for the query string, is there any way to make the browser cache it?

The urls would look something like:

```
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/magic.jpg?WSAccessKeyId=stuff&Signature=stuff&Expires=1276297463
http://example.s3.amazonaws.com/magic.jpg?WSAccessKeyId=stuff&Signature=stuff&Expires=1276297500
```

We plan to set the e-tags to be an md5sum, so will it at least figure out it's the same image at that point?

My other option is to keep track of when last gave out a url, then start giving out new ones slightly before the old ones expire, but I'd prefer not to deal with session info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser will use the entire URL for caching purposes, including request parameters.  So if you change a request parameter it will effectively be a new "key" in the cache and will always download a new copy of that image.  This is a popular technique in the ad-serving world - you add a random number (or the current timestamp) to the end of the URL as a parameter to ensure the browser always goes back to the server to make a new request.

The only way you might get this to work is if you can make the URL static - i.e. by using Apache rewrite rules or a proxy of some sort.

Comment: Do you know if it will at least check the e-tag and not download it again?

Comment: The ETag header is only sent by the browser to the server when it finds the file in it's cache (and if the original file had an ETag value).  So if it can't find it in its cache (which it won't if the URL has changed), there's no ETag value to send in the request.

Comment: The URL rewrite rule would then again make the S3 signature useless, because the web server would automatically provide a not expired link. Then you could also mark files in S3 as "public". (Then, no signature is required to access the files)

Answer (score 5):

I've been having exactly the same issue with S3 signed URLs.  The only solution I came up with is to have the URLs expire on the same day.  This is not ideal but at least it will provide caching for some time.

For example all URLs signed during April I set the expiry on May 10th.  All URLs signed in June I set to expire on July 10th.  This means the signed URLs will be identical for the whole month.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on this problem and found a way to solve it. Here's what you need to do:

1. Store first url string (in `localStorage` for example);
2. When you receive img url next time just check if their main urls match (`str1.split('?')[0] === str2.split('?')[0]`)
3. If they do, use the first one as img `src` attribute.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your owning browser caching mechanism using [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Cache)

See [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805423/824979)

Comment: What's the memory limit on Cache vs native browser cache?